# Add data from multiple dataframe by its index using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

So i got my dataframe (df1):

```
Number    Name       Gender  Hobby
122       John       Male      -
123       Patrick    Male      -
124       Rudy       Male      -
```

I want to add data to hobby based on number column. Assuming i've got my list of hobby based on its number on different dataframe. Like Example (df2):

```
Number    Hobby
124       Soccer
...         ...
...         ...
```

and df3 :

```
Number    Hobby
122       Basketball
...         ...
...         ...
```

How can i achieve this dataframe:

```
Number    Name       Gender  Hobby
122       John       Male    Basketball
123       Patrick    Male      -
124       Rudy       Male    Soccer
```

So far i've already tried this following solutions :

[Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

but its only selecting some data. How can i update the 'Hobby' column ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simple assignment `df['Hobby'] = hobby`

Comment: What if the hobby index its not always same index in list?

Comment: im facing 2 dataframe here. each dataframe has different rows. i cant use that assignment.

Comment: how do you know which item belongs to which Number. Build a dictionary, list is of no use here then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map`, `merge` and `join` will also achieve it

```
df['Hobby']=df.Number.map(df1.set_index('Number').Hobby)
df
Out[155]: 
   Number     Name Gender   Hobby
0     122     John   Male     NaN
1     123  Patrick   Male     NaN
2     124     Rudy   Male  Soccer
```

Comment: thank you. what if i've got another df and i want map it into multiple dataframe. in this case just df1, can i add with df1 and df2 as well?

Comment: @Fregy yes you can repeat above